# Remove Checkboxes from Listview - vb6

Tags: vb6

I have a standard List View component using checkboxes, while populating its data I would like to remove the checkboxes of specific rows based on a criteria, at this moment I found no way of doing it and no alternative component to replace the listview and include checkboxes.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim clmX As ColumnHeader
   Dim itmX As ListItem
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 3
      Set clmX = ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add()
      clmX.Text = "Column " & i
   Next i

   ' Inclui 10 items com o mesmo ícone
   For i = 1 To 10
      Set itmX = ListView1.ListItems.Add()
      itmX.SmallIcon = 1
      itmX.Text = "ListItem " & i
      itmX.SubItems(1) = "Subitem 1"
      itmX.SubItems(2) = "Subitem 2"
      If i = 2 Then
      'here
       'itmX.removeCheckbox
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```